# Getting an unhandled promise rejection when seeding a SQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, model-view-controller, sequelize.js, seeding

Learning MVC, I'm trying to seed my database with dummy entries and I keep getting this error:

```
(node:19287) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
at Query.run (/Users/joshuaramat/Documents/projects/tech-blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:52:25)
at /Users/joshuaramat/Documents/projects/tech-blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:313:28
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async MySQLQueryInterface.bulkInsert (/Users/joshuaramat/Documents/projects/tech-blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:335:21)
at async recursiveBulkCreate (/Users/joshuaramat/Documents/projects/tech-blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1655:25)
at async Function.bulkCreate (/Users/joshuaramat/Documents/projects/tech-blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1744:12)
at async seedAll (/Users/joshuaramat/Documents/projects/tech-blog/seeds/index.js:14:3)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:19287) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19287) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

the following is the code used to seed my data:

```
const seedUsers = require('./user-seeds');
const seedPosts = require('./post-seeds');
const seedComments = require('./comment-seeds');
const seedVotes = require('./vote-seeds');

const sequelize = require('../config/connection');

const seedAll = async () => {
  await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  console.log('SEQUELIZE--------------');
  await seedUsers();
  console.log('USERS--------------');

  await seedPosts();
  console.log('POSTS--------------');

  await seedComments();
  console.log('COMMENTS--------------');

  await seedVotes();
  console.log('VOTES--------------');

  process.exit(0);
};

seedAll();
```

The error seems to occur after the seedPosts() function is called.
Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Use `try ... catch` and check the actual error.

Comment: You've called an `async` function (`seedAll`) from a CommonJS module without checking if the call returns a rejected promise. For more information try `seedAll().catch(err => console.log("seedAll error: ", err));` as the last line of the post.

Comment: @traktor Thank you! I inserted that into the last line and got a more specific error `Column 'id' cannot be null` Just trying to figure how that could be since the values are informed

Comment: The Javascript that's causing the error is certainly somewhere in one of your models or in one of the seed methods, rather than in the code you've shared. Based on the 'id cannot be null' error message, either you are explicitly trying to pass in an id value when seeding and it's evaluating to null, or Sequelize does not know that it is supposed to be populating/auto-incrementing the id column for you.